# Do emr-dynamodb-connector reads data in parallel

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb

Do [emr-dynamodb-connector](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector) reads data in parallel in spark? I checked that RDD which I am getting from it has only one partition.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

var jobConf = new JobConf(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
jobConf.set("dynamodb.input.tableName", "TableName")

jobConf.set("mapred.output.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat")
jobConf.set("mapred.input.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat")

var orders = sc.hadoopRDD(jobConf, classOf[DynamoDBInputFormat], classOf[Text], classOf[DynamoDBItemWritable])
```

Above code to read data from DynamoDB. Following is the number of partitions.

```
scala> orders.getNumPartitions
res4: Int = 1
```

Is there any way to read data in parallel and process it?